# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS for iOS App - Not All Users

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

We have a small but significant percentage of our iPad app users crashing from an error that we can't replicate on either our simulators or any of our devices here. Not sure if this makes a difference, but we've spoken with a few users with the issue and they are all using an iPad 4.

Any ideas on how we can fix it without being able to replicate it?

Here's the log:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001955540b8 objc_retain + 24
1  AppName                        0x00000001000a6214 -[EDSSpeechButton initWithFrame:] (EDSSpeechButton.m:29)
2  AppName                        0x00000001000a1670 -[EDSLandPageScenarioViewController viewWillAppear:] (EDSLandPageScenarioViewController.m:68)
3  UIKit                          0x000000018bb440c0 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 452
4  UIKit                          0x000000018bcd9938 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 912
5  UIKit                          0x000000018bbe3f54 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 464
6  UIKit                          0x000000018bbe3d24 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 56
7  UIKit                          0x000000018bbe3ca4 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 200
8  UIKit                          0x000000018bb26ff8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 348
9  QuartzCore                     0x000000018b718258 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
10 QuartzCore                     0x000000018b712e20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 300
11 QuartzCore                     0x000000018b712cd8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
12 QuartzCore                     0x000000018b712560 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 280
13 QuartzCore                     0x000000018b712304 CA::Transaction::commit() + 424
14 UIKit                          0x000000018bb2b16c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9800
15 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188b23044 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
16 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188b223a0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256
17 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188b20638 __CFRunLoopRun + 632
18 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000188a616d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
19 GraphicsServices               0x000000018e6fdc0c GSEventRunModal + 168
20 UIKit                          0x000000018bb92fdc UIApplicationMain + 1156
21 AppName                        0x000000010009a3d0 main (main.m:16)
22 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000195b2faa0 start + 4
```

Here's the implementation of `initWithFrame`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame

{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {



        self.synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];

        self.synthesizer.delegate = self;

        speechPaused = NO;

        self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64);
        self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.button.hidden = YES;
        [self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
        [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(playPauseButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"voiceClipIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self addSubview:self.button];


        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSString *hasAudio = [prefs objectForKey:@"hasAudio"];


        if([hasAudio isEqualToString:@"1"]  && IS_IOS7==YES)

        {

            self.button.hidden = NO;

        }

    }

    return self;

}
```

**EDIT:** Here's where the crash happens:

```
EDSSpeechButton.m line 29
-[EDSSpeechButton initWithFrame:]
```

Line 29: `self.button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64);`

**UPDATE**: After speaking with more users- it seems the crash is isolated to 4th generation iPads.

Comment: Which line exactly in initWithFrame is causing the crash?

Comment: what is the crash reason? bad access or ?

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020`

Comment: is your EDSLandPageScenarioViewController viewWillAppear methods called with isAnimating variable true ?

Comment: if view is appearing with animation i have a theory